# Value Set in Oracle Apps using Union

Tags: oracle

I need to create a value set which selects items from a custom table for certain run no and union it with Select 'ALL' from dual so that when the user selects ALL the program runs for all the items. 
I tried creating a view of the custom table and then used

```
select item from xx_cust_view where run_no=:$FLEX$.RUN_NO_VS union select 'ALL' from dual
```

It is saved without error in value set but gives an error when I try to pass values while running the program.
Please suggest.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](try to solve your own problem first),
and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166)
(ignore if you're not asking about hw).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I tried this but it did not work (select item from xx_cust_view where run_no=:$FLEX$.RUN_NO_VS union select 'ALL' from dual)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Oracle Apps. but I thought that the following example might give you an idea.

It is ran in SQL*Plus, based on HR's *departments* table. Parameter PAR_DNAME accepts either real *department name* (such as "Purchasing") or *ALL* (which is then supposed to return all departments). ROWNUM is here just to restrict number of returned rows (so that I wouldn't display all 27 departments).

Have a look:

```
SQL> select * from departments
  2  where department_name =
  3    case when '&&par_dname' = 'ALL' then department_name
  4         else '&&par_dname'
  5    end
  6    --
  7    and rownum <= 5;
Enter value for par_dname: Purchasing

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
           30 Purchasing                            114        1700

SQL> undefine par_dname
SQL> /
Enter value for par_dname: ALL

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
           10 Administration                        200        1700
           20 Marketing                             201        1800
           30 Purchasing                            114        1700
           40 Human Resources                       203        2400
           50 Shipping                              121        1500

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Value set does not allow union, group by .
So i created a view of the union query and used this view in the value set to fetch the values.